# Sudden appereance of STIX fonts in math rendering

Tags: support, mathjax

I've recently started seeing STIX fonts in the $\LaTeX$ math rendering instead of the usual TeX fonts. I tried to fix it following the advice in [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12281/mathjax-graphics-change-with-stix-fonts) with no effect. Is anyone experiencing something similar?

Possibly related: the link in the [Mathjax 2.6 post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21505/mathjax-2-6-beta/21506#21506) says that I have the old fonts installed, even after I re-erased and re-installed the new fonts.

I am using chrome on OSX Yosemite. My current settings are to use fast-HTML rendering and TeX (local) fonts.